# Error: Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: iphone, swift

When I put the following code in my project

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)!) * 10, CGFloat((data?.acceleration.y)!) * 10)
```

I get an error

> Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to know more about a method/property, go to the documentation. For the initializer of `CGVector`, here is the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgvector/1455419-init).

Look at the initializer's declaration:

init(dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat)

Note how there are the argument labels `dx` and `dy`. This means that when you call the method, you should add those in your method call.

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(
    dx: CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)!) * 10, 
    dy: CGFloat((data?.acceleration.y)!) * 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGVector(dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat)
```

You aren't using the correct initializer for CGVector.

```swift
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(
dx: CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)!) * 10,
dy: CGFloat((data?.acceleration.y)!) * 10)
```

This should work.